# jQuery removes class when site reloads

Tags: jquery, dom, onclick, addclass, removeclass

How can this be? I mean, if I click on an anchor, I see in Firebug that it gives the class, but when it starts to reload the page, the class is gone. How can I let the class stay there after reload? I tried `preventdefault`, but then I can't click on the anchor (it does nothing).

This is my code:

```
jQuery("a").click(function()
{
 jQuery("a").parent().removeClass("selected");

  jQuery(this).parent().addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: DOM manipulations done by javascript aren't persistant. You could create a cookie referencing the selected item and adding the class on page load.

Comment: Creating a cookie? Damn, never done that. I have to sort that out than. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'd actually advise against cookies, and instead use sessionStorage, or localStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used my own solution

`jQuery('my-list-goes-here a[href*="'+window.location.href+'"]').addClass('add-class-name-here');`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trigger your action on the click of the  element, wait for the page loading and use the pathname to determine the clicked link

```
$(function() {

 var pathname = window.location.pathname;

 $("a").parent().removeClass("selected");
 $("a[href='"+ pathname +"']").parent().addClass('selected');

});
```